# Find cdf given pdf.

Tags: probability-distributions

> Let $X$ be the lifetime of a personal computer. Suppose the pdf of $X$ is 
>   $$
> f_X(x) = \begin{cases}\frac{1}{5}e^{-\frac{1}{5}x} & x > 0 \\ 0 & {\rm otherwise}\end{cases}
> $$
>   Assume that costumers replace their computers at failure or three years, whichever comes first. Let the actual life of a computer, which denoted the duration of a computer kept by an costumer before replacement.
>
> (a) Find the cdf of $F_T(t)$ of the actual life $T$ of a computer and then write it in one formula using the unit step functions

I learn that i can get the cdf by integrating the pdf.
$$\int 1/5e^{-t/5} \,dt= -e^{-t/5}$$
my way to get the cdf :
\begin{cases}
0  & \text{$t<0$} \\
-e^{-t/5} & \text{0≤t≤3}\\
1 & \text{$t>3$}
\end{cases}$
solution:
\begin{cases}
0  & \text{$t<0$} \\
1-e^{-t/5} & \text{0≤t≤3}\\
1 & \text{$t>3$}
\end{cases}$

Hope someone can explain why it is $1-e^{-1/5t}$ and the meaning of it.

Comment: Please phrase your question properly.

Comment: what is "the lifetime of the computer for 2 years"?

Comment: Please, it is $e^{-t/5}$ not $e^{-1/5t}$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Note that

> $t < 0$

$$
\int_{-\infty}^{t} {\rm d}t~ f_T(t) = 0
$$

> $t>0$

$$
\int_{-\infty}^{t} {\rm d}t~ f_T(t) = \int_{-\infty}^{0} {\rm d}t~ f_T(t) + \int_{0}^{t} {\rm d}t~ f_T(t) = 0 + \int_{0}^{t} {\rm d}t~ \frac{1}{5}e^{-t/5} = 1 - e^{-t/5}
$$

So in summary

$$
F_T(t) = \left\{\begin{array}{ccc} 0 &,& t < 0 \\ 1 - e^{-t/5} &,& t\ge 0\end{array}\right.
$$

Answer (score 0):

You should integrate from $0$ to $t$. This gives you
$$
\frac{1}{5} \int_0^t e^{-\frac{1}{5}x} = 1-e^{-\frac{1}{5}t}.
$$